# Receiving "ERROR" message from SIM800C module

Tags: hardware, mobile-data, gsm

Most of the commands I send to [SIM800C](https://www.elecrow.com/download/SIM800C_Hardware_Design_V1.02.pdf) module returns `ERROR` message to me.

*For example:*

If I sent `AT+CSQ`, it returns an expected response.

One of the basics commands that doesn't worked for me is the `AT+CPIN?` PIN checking command.

In the datasheet, I don't even can find the possible cause for this error.

*Another information I have:*

Among many explanations for the problem, I found one, and I don't remember which was, that said to send a command to expand `ERROR` in details. As result from `AT+CPIN?`, I received a error that corresponds to "no card inserted" and I don't know why. The SIM card works fine, I have tested on my phone.

The SIM card is not detected by module. I measured the voltage in the card bus and I have 0 volts. I don't know it is the cause or the consequence for bad functioning, not even it is related to this main problem of this question.

*This is my circuit:*

[image: SIM800 circuit sheet]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your setup? What is connected to what? Who sends the commands, etc...

Comment: It is you who designed and built the hardware around the module or you bought a SIM800 breakout board? In the first case please share your schematics in second share a link about the breakout board. Also verify with phone that the SIM card is alright and detectable by other devices.

Comment: SIM card holder footprint is double checked? So the correct pins are connected?

Comment: I checked the connections between the SIM card holder and module and footprints. They are perfect.

Comment: I found here (http://www.microchip.com/forums/FindPost/621998) a way to check for the VDD signals on the SIM card. And it sends 1.8 and 3.3V signals correctly. In that post, @rpg7 says the card responds with a reset pulse from card reset pin. I could read ~15ms reset pulse with a scope. So it seams to work fine.

Comment: I checked the bus signal again and I can see a 3.25MHz clock on SIM card bus and a 40 ms positive pulse on data pin.

Comment: Very, very, very wild guess - 3rd gen SIM on a 2nd gen board?

Comment: It's not a dev. board. It just the module. Or I should know this information about the module?

Comment: Can you observe any noise or strange thing on the clock and data lines? There are some PCB design guide in the datasheet regarding the SIM holder, and I see a couple of things like series resistors and 22 pF filter capacitor on data line are missing from your design.

Comment: There is no noise on the bus. It maybe on low voltage scales, but I'm sure is nothing significative for the bus standards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was bad contacting between SIM card contact block and the board. The problem was difficult to find because when I touched the terminal for measurement it makes pressure to the board, the contact happens and the problem couldn't be observed.

I made a check list for resolution:

- Is SIM card working?
- Are voltages on card correct?
- Can bus signals be seen in a scope?
- Is SIM card contacts block footprint correct?
- Is card in the correct position?
- Are SIM card VDD and GND both connected?

After eliminated most of all those questions the only possibility was the last one. Fact! I touched GND in the card holder very very delicately and the problem was there, a Heisenbug.

I hope this answer and checklist help a lot, because information about this kind of problem is very difficult to find.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable extended error reporting, by sending `AT+CERR`.

Different devices will give different informaiton, but you should at least get some diagnostic help/hint.

> For instance, [this page](http://www.activexperts.com/sms-component/at/commands/?at=%2BCEER) says
>
> AT+CEER - Extended error report
>
> Execution command causes the TA to return one or more lines of
>   information text , determined by the ME manufacturer, which
>   should offer the user of the TA an extended report of the reason for
>
> - *the failure in the last unsuccessful call setup (originating or answering)*
> - *or in-call modification,*
> - *the last call release,*
> - *the last unsuccessful GPRS attach or unsuccessful PDP context activation,
>     the last GPRS detach or PDP context deactivation.*
>
> Typically, the text will consist of a single line containing the cause
>   information given by GSM network in textual format.
>
> Defined values
>
> <report>: 
>       the total number of characters, including line terminators,
>   in the information text shall not exceed 2041 characters. Text shall
>   not contain the sequence 0 or OK

Comment: I performed this command and the only I receive is +CEER: No cause. Check my edits in my question. I put there some other information about the error.